# "Preimage" of a binary relation

Tags: reference-request, elementary-set-theory, notation, definition, relations

Consider the binary relation $R \subseteq X \times Y$. Is there a standard name and notation for the set $X' = \{x\ |\ (x, y) \in R\}$?

- [ProofWiki](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition%3aPreimage) calls $X'$ the *preimage* of $R$, denoted as
  $\operatorname{Im}^{-1}(R)$.
- [This site](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~alspaugh/cls/shr/correspondence.html) calls $R$ a *correspondence*, calls $X$ the *predomain* of $R$ and calls $X'$ the *domain* of $R$.

Both conventions seem to make sense, although $X$ is generally called the domain of $R$, which I prefer as well. But the notation $\operatorname{Im}^{-1}(R)$ is rather clunky and unwieldy - not to mention that I hardly see it elsewhere - and I would prefer to use something simpler like $\operatorname{dom} R$ or $\operatorname{pre} R$, if these are accepted.

Of course, I should follow the standard notation, but I can't seem  to find a consensus online!

Comment: I think $\operatorname{dom} (R)$ is much more common.

Comment: @GitGud If I'm not wrong, $\operatorname{dom}(R)$ usually refers to $X$, especially in the context of Category Theory... but my background knowledge is still really weak, so is $\operatorname{dom}(R)$ the norm elsewhere?

Comment: I know nothing about Category Theory. In elementary set theory $\operatorname{dom}(R)$ is standard notation for $\{x\in X\colon \exists y\in Y((x,y)\in R)\}$.

Comment: @GitGud I see, could you provide some more or less authoritative reference for this notation? If it seems standard enough you can post that as an answer too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I claimed in a comment that $\operatorname{dom}(R)$ is standard notation. I was asked by the OP to give out some references to support this claim. I present them below.

> From [D.J. Velleman](http://www.cs.amherst.edu/~djv/)'s [How to Prove It: A Structured Approach](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521675995):
>   [image: Vellleman]
>
> From [Elements of Set Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0122384407) by [H. B. Enderton](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~hbe/):
>   [image: Enderton]
>
> And finally, from [Thomas Jech](http://www.math.cas.cz/~jech/)'s classic [Set Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540440852):
>   [image: Jech]

Comment: Thanks, I'm sufficiently convinced ;) Just curious, what is the name or notation for $X$ or $Y$?

Comment: @HerngYi I'm afraid I don't know what you mean with '$X$ or $Y$'. Do you mean [disjuction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction)?

Comment: I meant "what is the name for $X$, and what is the name for $Y$?" Sorry for the confusion haha

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have those books so could I check one more thing with you? Can I write the image (resp. preimage) of a set $A$ under $R$ as $R[A]$ (resp. $R^{-1}[A]$)? I saw this notation somewhere and it seems rather nice...

Comment: @HerngYi The notation for $Y$ is, as you can see above, $\operatorname{ran}(R)$ or any variation of that and it's called *range*. The notations $R[A\bf]$ and $R^{-1}[A\bf]$ are standard. Note, however, that $R^{-1}[A\bf]$ can have two different meanings: one is the image of $A$ by the relation $R^{-1}$, whilst the other is the inverse image of $A$ relative to the relation $R$. Fortunately they coincide, which rids us of ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying on images and preimages. But by $Y$ I'm referring to my OP, in which $Y$ is the universe from which the pairs in $R$ draw their second entry from. That is, $\operatorname{ran}(R)$ is embedded in $Y$ and may even be a proper subset (e.g. when $R$ is a non-surjective function)

Comment: @HerngYi I apologize for misunderstanding. It's common to call $Y$ the *codomain*.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11125/discussion-between-herng-yi-and-git-gud)

Answer (score 1):

In:

J.Riguet, "Relations binaires, fermetures, correspondances de Galois." Bulletin de la Société Mathématique de France, **76** (1948), pp.114-155

$X'$ is denoted as ${\rm pr_1}R$ (the first projection).

Comment: I see, that makes sense! If $\operatorname{pr}_1$ is the "canonical projection" to the first element (although more commonly denoted by $\pi_1$ I think) then the image of $R$ under $\operatorname{pr}_1$ is $X'$! Nice, but I'm hoping for something more standard.

Comment: N.Bourbaki in "Theorie des Ensembles" also used this notation.

Comment: It's indeed borrowed from Bourbaki. Interestingly, in Bourbaki there is no name for $X$, $Y$ because there is none! indeed a "graph" is defined as a set of pairs (with the intrinsic notion of pairs: a set $p$ is a pair if there exist $x,y$ such that $\{x,\{y\}\}$).